# Compute 3D point from mouse-position and depth-map

Tags: three.js, raycasting, depth-buffer, projection-matrix

I need to compute 3D coordinates from a screen-space position using a rendered depth-map. Unfortunately, using the regular raytracing is not an option for me because I am dealing with a single geometry containing something on the order of 5M faces.

So I figured I will do the following:

- render a depth-map with RGBADepthPacking into a renderTarget
- use a regular unproject-call to compute a ray from the mouse-position (exactly as I would do when using raycasting)
- lookup the depth from the depth-map at the mouse-coordinates and compute a point along the ray using that distance.

[This kind of works](https://jsfiddle.net/mpspb7jn/1/), but somehow the located point is always slightly behind the object, so there is probably something wrong with my depth-calculations.

### Now some details about the steps above

Rendering the depth-map is pretty much straight-forward:

```
const depthTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(w, h);
const depthMaterial = new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial({
  depthPacking: THREE.RGBADepthPacking
});

// in renderloop
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
renderer.clear();
scene.overrideMaterial = depthMaterial;
renderer.render(scene, camera, depthTarget);
```

Lookup the stored color-value at the mouse-position with:

```
renderer.readRenderTargetPixels(
  depthTarget, x, h - y, 1, 1, rgbaBuffer
);
```

And convert back to float using (adapted from the GLSL-Version in packing.glsl):

```
const v4 = new THREE.Vector4()
const unpackDownscale = 255 / 256;
const unpackFactors = new THREE.Vector4(
  unpackDownscale / (256 * 256 * 256),
  unpackDownscale / (256 * 256),
  unpackDownscale / 256,
  unpackDownscale
);

function unpackRGBAToDepth(rgbaBuffer) {
  return v4.fromArray(rgbaBuffer)
    .multiplyScalar(1 / 255)
    .dot(unpackFactors);
}
```

and finally computing the depth-value (I found corresponding code in readDepth() in `examples/js/shaders/SSAOShader.js` which I ported to JS):

```
function computeDepth() {
  const cameraFarPlusNear = cameraFar + cameraNear;
  const cameraFarMinusNear = cameraFar - cameraNear;
  const cameraCoef = 2.0 * cameraNear;

  let z = unpackRGBAToDepth(rgbaBuffer);
  return cameraCoef / (cameraFarPlusNear - z * cameraFarMinusNear);
}
```

Now, as this function returns values in range 0..1 I think it is the depth in clip-space coordinates, so I convert them into "real" units using:

```
const depth = camera.near + depth * (camera.far - camera.near);
```

There is obviously something slightly off with these calculations and I didn't figure out the math and details about how depth is stored yet. 
Can someone please point me to the mistake I made?

### Addition: other things I tried

First I thought it should be possible to just use the unpacked depth-value as value for z in my unproject-call like this:

```
const x = mouseX/w * 2 - 1;
const y = -mouseY/h * 2 + 1;
const v = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, depth).unproject(camera);
```

However, this also doesn't get the coordinates right.

**[EDIT 1 2017-05-23 11:00CEST]**

As per @WestLangleys comment I found the `perspectiveDepthToViewZ()` function which sounds like it should help. Written in JS that function is

```
function perspectiveDepthToViewZ(invClipZ, near, far) {
  return (near * far) / ((far - near) * invClipZ - far);
}
```

However, when called with unpacked values from the depth-map, results are several orders of magnitude off. [See here](https://jsfiddle.net/mpspb7jn/4/).

Comment: Maybe these will help: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/packing.glsl, https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_depth_texture.html

Comment: Are you assuming that your depth buffer is linear? I'm not entirely sure if you already considered that, but it may be whats throwing off your math.

Comment: @WestLangley thanks! I didn't notice the `perspectiveDepthToViewZ()`-function there, but unfortunately a) I still don't quite understand the math and b) the results, when supplied a depth-buffer value don't make any sense to me.

Comment: @pailhead Already considered that, which is why I originally wanted to just reverse the perspective transform. At this point I'm just trying things until I get numbers that make sense :/

Comment: @WestLangley: Turns out, I was doing it wrong and the solution with `perspectiveDepthToViewZ()` now has convincing results. If you add that as an answer I will happily accept it. Otherwise I will add it myself tomorrow...

Comment: That's OK, you can post it. :)

Comment: @user5515 I have updated the original https://jsfiddle.net/mpspb7jn/1/ with current r152 THREE version: https://codesandbox.io/s/mouse-depth-h9qz2r This does NOT include latest (2017-05-28) Martin's answer though

Comment: Using "postprocessing" DepthPickingPass (GPU-based), I managed to get a totally similar example working: https://codesandbox.io/embed/depth-picking-x130hg?codemirror=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so. Finally solved it. So for everyone having trouble with similar issues, here's the solution:

The last line of the computeDepth-function was just wrong. There is a function `perspectiveDepthToViewZ` in `packing.glsl`, that is pretty easy to convert to JS:

```
function perspectiveDepthToViewZ(invClipZ, near, far) {
  return (near * far) / ((far - near) * invClipZ - far);
}
```

(i believe this is somehow part of the inverse projection-matrix)

```
function computeDepth() {
  let z = unpackRGBAToDepth(rgbaBuffer);
  return perspectiveDepthToViewZ(z, camera.near, camera.far);
}
```

Now this will return the z-axis value in view-space for the point. Left to do is converting this back to world-space coordinates:

```
const setPositionFromViewZ = (function() {
  const viewSpaceCoord = new THREE.Vector3();
  const projInv = new THREE.Matrix4();

  return function(position, viewZ) {
    projInv.getInverse(camera.projectionMatrix);
    position
      .set(
        mousePosition.x / windowWidth * 2 - 1,
        -(mousePosition.y / windowHeight) * 2 + 1,
        0.5
      )
      .applyMatrix4(projInv);

    position.multiplyScalar(viewZ / position.z);
    position.applyMatrix4(camera.matrixWorld);
  };
}) ();
```

Comment: Can you please update the jsfiddle with the correct solution, for us mortals to understand it?

Comment: Awesome, I was trying to figure out a solution for days, and I couldn't do it with just two passes -I'll study it exhaustively, many thanks! :)